# jQuery listen for change events by hexagon.js slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have downloaded a hexagon.js to use their sliders (https://hexagonjs.io/docs/slider/).
In my html, i have inserted

```
<div class="slider" class="hx-slider"></div>
```

And to javascript

```
$('.slider').each(function(){
slider = new hx.Slider(this); });
```

and

```
slider.on('change', function(){
console.log("test"); });
```

And this works fine, but as expected, problems stars when i add more than one slider.
Then, only the latest created slider will "catch" the event.

I am aware why is it happening, but i do not know how to do it properly.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$(".slider").on("change", function() {
    console.log("test");
});
```

This will attach the "change" event on all `.slider` elements.

**EDIT:**

According to the [slider docs](https://hexagonjs.io/docs/slider/), there is `change` event for the slider component. So you could do something like:

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    slider = new hx.Slider(this);
    slider.change(function(value) {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

Good luck!